# Cumulative users tooltip counts users incorrectly, cooks the books

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

On the [All time leagues page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) there's a tool tip on the number 190 that reads

> Cumulative users: 244

[image: reputation with tooltip showing cumulative count]

What are these numbers supposed to mean? At first glance I thought it meant that

```
Count of users where (Rep >= 50K and rep < 100K)  = 190
Count of users where (Rep >= 50K)                 = 244
```

However, there are only ~190 that have more than 50K, not ~244.

[image: rep league at the #191 point]

Ingoring the possibility that the calculation of rank and the counts were against slightly different datasets due to caching issues, I don't understand what the 244 is supposed to represent.

Comment: I noticed that too, the numbers listed under `Users` are actually the cumulative numbers already.

Comment: Actually, even in that case, the number is off by 1.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I suspect it's another of those daily update things.

Comment: It's an election year. Time to double dip the numbers

Comment: @random Is that like a leap year? `:)`

Comment: I think that this is easily solved by just getting rid of the tooltip or making it accumulate in the other direction, because the table itself already shows the cumulative counts. That's why there is a `+` in `50,000+`. Perhaps they were using a table helper that adds cumulative tool tips by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leagues code was majorly refactored in early March (it's now exactly accurate in theory, whereas before, it was always slightly off).

In the process, I inadvertently changed the behavior of the "Reputation Change" and "Total Reputation" sidebar stats modules. Before, "50,000+" corresponded to `x >= 50k && x < 100k`, whereas now, as you noticed, it corresponds to just `x >= 50k`. Consequently, the tooltips are meaningless and wrong.

Even though I introduced the new behavior by accident, I think I like it more. So, I removed the tooltips. Thanks for the report.

Comment: I liked the old way better (two data points is better than one IMHO) but I can see how it may have been confusing. Thanks for addressing it.

Comment: While you're there, I notice that sidebar says "Total Rep*" -> "* users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues", but right above that it has a 1+ rep category, which sounds like they are tracked.